# List subjects to open list sub-subjects

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to android, trying to create a list that opens up another list. Like subjects (eg math, science) opens up another list of sub-subjects/topics eg calculus. This is what i have, doesn't add sub-subjects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contentListLv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity code

```
package com.example.loginreg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ContentListActivity extends Activity {
ListView content_list_lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_list);

    //final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentListLv);

    String[] math= new String[] { "Calculus", "Trigonometry", "Algebra" };


    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    content_list_lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentListLv);

    for (int i = 0; i < math.length; ++i) {
        list.add(math[i]);
        //list.add(science[i]);
    }

    String[] science = new String[] { "Anatomy", "Chemistry and Biology", "Space" };
    final ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int j=0; j<science.length; ++j) {
        list2.add(science[j]);
    }

    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    //science
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter2 = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, list2);


    content_list_lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    content_list_lv
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0);
                    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ContentActivity.class);



                    l.putExtra("ContentName", item);
                    l.putExtra("ContentId", id);

                    startActivity(l);

                }

            });

    content_list_lv
    .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0);
            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ContentActivity.class);



            l.putExtra("ContentName", item);
            l.putExtra("ContentId", id);

            startActivity(l);

        }

    });

}
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.content_list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html